# How do I go about user uploading files and retrieval on page load?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, image-uploading, server

I'm doing a yelp listings of sorts where a company can upload their logos and it'll be displayed when the user loads the company page. I'm doing this with Ruby/Sinatra and I very well know how to handle file uploading and saving it on the server. I'm uploading files with this particular structure - /images/%uploaded_year%/%uploaded_month%/%filename%

I've successfully managed to put the files in the respected directories. My question is, what should be the best method of retrieving the images when a user requests it? Should i insert the image path on the database? Or is there another way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is to store the image url in database column. As soon you get request for page you can retrieve the image url.